# how to convert my data frame to xts objects? each one should have the dates and the returns of the portfolio whose name is located in first column

Tags: r, xts

[I obtain my information from an excel file that contains the daily returns of many different portfolios for one year. My data looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5Lxf.jpg).I hid the returns for legal reasons.
I want to make one xts object for each portfolio containing only the dates and the returns. Keep in mind that the portfolios more than 200 in number, I do not want to do it manually.

Comment: Please do not share data as images. Use ``dput()`` instead.

Answer (score 0):

To create an xts object, first convert your targeted column in your data frame (in your case, the `active_returns`) to a matrix, and then set the `dates` column as the row names of the matrix. Then, you convert the matrix to an xts object using `as.xts` function.

You don't provide any data frame as an example, so here is one:

```
set.seed(1)
dates <- seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-10"), by = "days")
portfolios <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], size = 10, replace = TRUE )
returns <- runif(10, min = 10, max = 100)
dat <- data.frame(dates, portfolios, returns)
dat
#        dates  portfolios  returns
# 1  2020-01-01          A 25.89011
# 2  2020-01-02          C 71.83206
# 3  2020-01-03          A 44.56933
# 4  2020-01-04          B 79.28573
# 5  2020-01-05          A 54.79293
# 6  2020-01-06          C 74.58567
# 7  2020-01-07          C 99.27155
# 8  2020-01-08          B 44.20317
# 9  2020-01-09          B 79.97007
# 10 2020-01-10          C 94.12347
```

It's efficient to wrap the steps in a function that takes a data frame as its argument.

```
library(xts)
make_xts <- function(yourdf){
  dat_matrix <- as.matrix(yourdf["returns"])
  rownames(dat_matrix) <- unlist(as.character.Date(yourdf["dates"]))
  return(as.xts(dat_matrix))
}
```

Then, this function can be applied to the targeted data frame for each group. For example, the group variable is `portfolios`

In base-R, you can use `by`:

```
xts_list <- by(dat, dat$portfolios, make_xts)
xts_list
# dat$portfolios: A
# returns
# 2020-01-01 25.89011
# 2020-01-03 44.56933
# 2020-01-05 54.79293
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
#   dat$portfolios: B
# returns
# 2020-01-04 79.28573
# 2020-01-08 44.20317
# 2020-01-09 79.97007
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
#   dat$portfolios: C
# returns
# 2020-01-02 71.83206
# 2020-01-06 74.58567
# 2020-01-07 99.27155
# 2020-01-10 94.12347
```

The result is a list, so you can subset any element of it by using `$`:

```
xts_list$A
            returns
2020-01-01 25.89011
2020-01-03 44.56933
2020-01-05 54.79293
```

To check if it is really an xts object:

```
str(xts_list$A)
# An ‘xts’ object on 2020-01-01/2020-01-05 containing:
#   Data: num [1:3, 1] 25.9 44.6 54.8
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
# ..$ : NULL
# ..$ : chr "returns"
# Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: 
#   xts Attributes:  
#   NULL
```